# Change specific name:value pair in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parseint

I'm trying to simply write a function to convert one of the property values in my JS object to an integer - specifically, convert the weight property for each fruit from string ("200g") to an int (200)

```
var basket = [
  {
    name: "apple",
    weight: "200g",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    name: "bananas",
    weight: "90g",
    type: "fruit"
  },
   ];
```

I'd like to write a fnc to convert the weight from str to int and then save the whole thing as a new JS object - new_basket.
I'm not quite sure how to structure functions in JS but i have sthing like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<basket.length; i++) {
    new_basket = parseInt(basket.weight);
    console.log(new_basket)
}
```

I've seen examples with forEach but they would convert all the properties whilst i just would like all the weights converted.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var basket = [
  {
    name: "apple",
    weight: "200g",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    name: "bananas",
    weight: "90g",
    type: "fruit"
  },
   ];

basket.forEach((data,i)=>{
  data['weight']=Number(String(data['weight']).replace('g',''))
})
console.log(basket);
```

Here you go, hope this helps. if so I'm glad!

```
basket.forEach((data,i)=>data['weight']=Number(String(data['weight']).replace('g','')));
```

in a single line, clean code do the modification to the existing array.

Answer (score 1):

`basket` is a list, so you need to access every object with the `[]` operator. You can do it in the following way:

```js
var basket = [
  {
    name: "apple",
    weight: "200g",
    type: "fruit"
  },
  {
    name: "bananas",
    weight: "90g",
    type: "fruit"
  },
];

for(var i=0; i<basket.length; i++) {
    new_basket = parseInt(basket[i].weight);
    console.log(new_basket)
}
```

Comment: For the questions regarding web dev, you could use runnable code snippets. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `Object.assign` to merge the new key/value with the original object, *inside of a new object*.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

As an aside, using a higher order function, like `map` can make your code a bit more readable and allows for chaining. `map` iterates through an array and returns a new array. It accepts a callback where all of your transformations can happen.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

In your case, you can try something like this:

```
const newFruits = fruits.map(fruit => {
    return Object.assign(fruit, { weight: parseInt(fruit.weight) })
})
```

The function loops through the results, and then uses `Object.assign` to merge the new key/value with the original object.

Here's the obligatory ES6 [and shorthand] approach:

```
const newFruits = fruits.map(({weight, ...fruit}) => ({
    ...fruit,
    weight: +weight
})
```